# How to pass and retrieve key value from navigationoptions in createStackNavigator react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, stack-navigator

We are trying to pass Key value from stacknavigator through navigationoptions, But, It is coming as undefined.

I am using following version of react-navigation

```
"react-navigation": "^3.0.9",

const Stack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Mobile: { screen: Mobile, navigationOptions: { header: null, Key: true } },
    Login: { screen: Login, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
    DB: { screen: DB, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Mobile',
  },
);
```

But, While trying to access that key value, Getting undefined.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const key = JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('key'));
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of react-navigation are you using ? Because i cannot find the `key` param in `navigationOptions` of a stackNavigator in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To use `getParam`, you need to first `setParams`. You can specify the key in the component where you created the `stack` variable.

In the below example, I used setParam in the same component. The function `getParam` is called, which prints the `name` param when you press on the `TouchableOpacity` in the `Mobile` component.

```
class Mobile extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.setParams({ name: 'Lucy' });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Mobile</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 200, width: 200}}
          onPress={() => console.log(this.props.navigation.getParam('name'))}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You can refer to documentation under the `setParam` section: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Comment: Please check my query once. I am sending through stacknavigator not by navigation.navigate